# Group by Eloquent Query Foreach in view

Tags: laravel

I want to group my results by "licencie_id" on my search Function but I get an exception when I put the "Group By" condition.

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

I have done this like :

```
$designations = $query->paginate(10)->groupBy('licencie_id');
```

When I debug I get:

```
Collection {#979 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    125 => Collection {#1010 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => RencontreOfficiel {#975 ▶}
        1 => RencontreOfficiel {#1006 ▶}
      ]
    }
    131 => Collection {#998 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
    134 => Collection {#1013 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I would like now to display this collection in my view like :

```
@foreach($designations as $designation)
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="{!! route('designation.show', $designation->id) !!}">{{$designation->id}}</a></td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->rencontre->compet->categorie_compet->lb_categorie_compet}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->rencontre->compet->lb_compet}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->fonction_officiel->lb_fonction}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->rencontre->dt_rencontre}} {{$designation->rencontre->time_rencontre}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->rencontre->equipe_domicile->lb_equipe}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->rencontre->equipe_visiteur->lb_equipe}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->licence->lb_nom}} {{$designation->licence->lb_prenom}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->bareme->lb_bareme}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->nm_distance}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->mt_indemnite_km}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->bareme->mt_prime}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$designation->statut_officiel}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

Where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making wrong the query builder, Eloquent ORM statments must be before the paginate:

```
$designations = $query->groupBy('licencie_id')->paginate(10)
```

By the way, reading the [Laravel pagination docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination) you can find:

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot
>   be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with
>   a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database
>   and create a paginator manually.

That means is something not working well with pagination plus a groupBy, I hardly recommend you skip using them together if you want to skip undesired  behavior.

Comment: thanks for your answer i deleted the paginate method ! now i get : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty()

Comment: @MathieuMourareau Then if this question is answered, it's time to write a new question about your new problem explaining the details :)

Comment: i had this exception before , could you help me ?

Comment: Looks you are doing something wrong in your model I guess you are trying to do a scope but without more code we can't help you, create a new question with more details about your model.

Comment: here the new post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888812/group-by-condition-in-an-eloquent-query