# Group By Condition in an Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel

I have an error when i try to make a Group By condition in my query , i get this exception :

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty()

Someone knows why i get this error ? It's because i didn't created a Scope in my Model ? Thanks a lot in advance friends .

Here my controller :

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $compet = Compet::pluck('lb_compet' , 'id');

    $structure = Structure::select('num_structure', 'nom_structure' , 'id')
        ->where('type_structure_id' , '1')
        ->orWhere('type_structure_id' , '2')
        ->orWhere('type_structure_id' , '3')
        ->get()
        ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
            return [$i->id => $i->num_structure.' - '.$i->nom_structure];
        });

    $catg_compet = CategorieCompet::pluck('lb_categorie_compet' , 'id');
    $fonction = FonctionOfficiel::pluck('lb_fonction' , 'id');
    $bareme = Bareme::pluck('lb_bareme' , 'id');
    $licence = Licencies::select('lb_nom', 'num_licence', 'lb_prenom', 'id' , 'structure_id' , 'activite_licencie_id')
        ->where('type_licence_id' , '1')
        ->get()
        ->mapWithKeys(function($i) {
            return [$i->id => $i->lb_nom.' - '.$i->lb_prenom.' - n°'.$i->num_licence.' - '.$i->activite_licencie->lb_activite.' - '.$i->structure->nom_structure];
        });


    $query = RencontreOfficiel::query()->orderBy('licencie_id');



    $filters = [
        'licencie_id' => 'licencie_id',
        'compet_id' => 'compet_id',
        'structure_id' => 'structure_id',
        'catg_compet_id' => 'dt_rencontre',
        'fonction_id' => 'dt_rencontre',
        'bareme_id' => 'bareme_id',
        'dt_min_rencontre' => 'dt_rencontre',
        'dt_max_rencontre' => 'dt_rencontre',

    ];

    $dt_min = $request->input('dt_rencontre_min');
    $dt_max = $request->input('dt_rencontre_max');

    foreach ($filters as $key => $column) {
        $query->when($request->{$key}, function ($query, $value) use ($column , $dt_min , $dt_max) {
            $query->where($column, $value)
                ->orWhereBetween('dt_rencontre' , [$dt_min , $dt_max]);

        });

    }

    // group by licence
    $designations = $query->groupBy('licencie_id');

    return view('designations/index' , compact('licence' , 'designations' , 'compet' , 'structure' , 'catg_compet' , 'fonction' , 'bareme'));

}
```

Here my model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Licencies extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'licencies';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = array('lb_nom', 'lb_photo', 'lb_prenom', 'dt_naissance', 'cd_dept_naissance', 'lb_ville_naissance', 'adresse_email');

   // use Searchable;

    public function structure()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Structure');
    }

    public function club()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Club');
    }

    public function pays()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Pays' , 'pays_naissance_id');
    }

    public function activite_licencie()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ActiviteLicencie' , 'activite_licencie_id');
    }


    public function saison()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Saison' , 'saison_id');

    }

    public function statut_licence()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LicenceStatut');

    }



    public function nationalite()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Nationalite');

    }

    public function civilite()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Civilite');

    }

    public function categorie_age() {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\CatgLicence' , 'catg_licence_id');

    }

    public function valide(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\LicenceValid' , 'valid_licence_id');
    }


    public function sanctions(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\LicenceSanction' , 'licencie_id');


    }

    public function type_licence(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type_licence');

    }

    public function equipes(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Equipe');

    }

    public function selections(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SelectionLicence' , 'licencie_id');

    }


    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['dt_naissance'])->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%y ans');

    }

    public function getSexeAttribute(){

        return str_limit($this->civilite->lb_civilite, 1 , '');
    }

    public function getActiviteAttribute(){

    return $this->activite_licencie->lb_activite;

    }

    //public function getNumLicencieAttribute() {
    //    $first = substr($this->num_licence, 0, 2); //from position 0, take 2 digits
    //    $second = substr($this->num_licence, 2, 2); //from position 2, take 2
    //    $third = substr($this->num_licence, 4); //from 4 take the rest.
    //    return $first . '-' . $second . '-' . $third;
   // }



}
```

Comment: where are you trying that group by condition?

Comment: how are you writing this $query?? can post the code

Comment: I updated my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missiong model class object here

```
 // group by licence
$designations = $query->groupBy('licencie_id');
```

you need to use Licencies object of model like

```
// group by licence
$designations = Licencies::groupBy('licencie_id')->get();
```

Comment: thanks fro your reply i still get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty()

Comment: please use get method to fetch records

Comment: i get now : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'ffr13licences.rencontre_officiel.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `rencontre_officiel` group by `licencie_id`)

Comment: i done this :  $designations = RencontreOfficiel::groupBy('licencie_id')->get();

Comment: Ok i resolved ! i had to change in config/database : 'strict' => true to 'strict' => false,